# If Exists command problems

Tags: batch-file

I created a batch file that is supposed to go into a folder to check to see if a file exists, and if it exists, it needs to copy that file to another directory. The problem is every time I try and run the batch file I get the error:

> "text.txt" was unexpected at this time

and currently I am running code similar to this: **(UPDATED)**

```
if exist "text.txt" (copy "text.txt" C:\directory\copiedFile)
```

Answer (score 8):

It should be `EXIST`, not `EXISTS`.

```
IF EXIST "text.txt" COPY C:\directory\copiedfile
```

Comment: haha okay, a little bit of a typo. Also when I run that command it copies everything from C:\directory\copiedfile into my the current directory. Even if I put IF Exists "text.txt" copy "text.txt" C:\directory\copiedfile

Comment: don't worry I found what the problem was

Comment: Great Answer: I ran into this myself. Ugh. I hate computers sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

I think the syntax you are using is a bit off.

IF EXIST text.txt (copy text.txt C:\directory\text_copy.txt)

Comment: ohh, ya i just figured that out