# Check if file named is there, if not, report back in text file

Tags: batch-file

I have a list of file names, of which I need to know if these are there.

And if they are not, I would like it to report only the file names, which are not found in the text file.

I did find these:

[If Exists command problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331422/if-exists-dos-command-problems)

You have my thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dir /b | findstr /v /x /g:/ mustBePresent.txt > missing.txt
```